# Unkown File permissions for /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: linux, permissions, resolv.conf

I am unable to ping any url (for example www.google.com), neither any of the website is working. However, I can ping static IPs (E.g. 8.8.8.8). A little debugging showed that the issue is /etc/resolv.conf file which got corrupted. It has very strange file permissions. 
`ls -l` shows question marks on resolv.conf

`drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Feb 17 05:59 request-key.d
-??????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? resolv.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root   4096 Dec 17  2015 rhsm`

It has ? (question mark) everywhere. Its not letting me run any command for this file. Running any command (like cat, rm, file) gives a same error.

```
rm: cannot remove `resolv.conf`: Input/output error
```

I tried booting with a live Ubuntu image and mounted the file system. I got  same results. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Unmount the filesystem and run fsck on it.

Comment: Most likely file system corruption. Since you are able to access your server, first secure important data and then perform fsck.

Comment: I ended up deleting whole disk and reinstalling OS from scratch, Thanks for the support guys